# supervisor start multiple children as atomic operation

Tags: erlang, atomic, erlang-supervisor

I need to start multiple supervisor children in an atomic way. That is, if one of children in group fails at startup then none of them should be started.

I see this operation as a function:

```
start_children(SupRef, ChildSpecs)
ChildSpecs = List :: [child_spec()]
```

How should I implement this in a proper way? Any examples, libraries etc.? My intuition tells me that starting all children from the list, checking if all of them were successful and then killing remaining ones is not the way.

Or perhaps my design is flawed and I really should not need to do such things?

Answer (score 2):

OTP's [supervisor](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) provides support for this with the `one_for_all` strategy. By default, if some process fails, all processes are restarted, but you can change this by using a suitable for your purpose `Restart` parameter (e.g. `temporary`).

Comment: Yes, but I would like to do this dynamically. With `one_for_all` if a child invoked with `start_child` fails, all children of this supervisor will be restarted (or killed), even the ones started previously. I do not want that. I want only children in the same list as failing one to be killed. Children started previously should not be touched.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have multiple children lists. And you only want to kill all children in a list if one of them fails, but not touch any children of another list. How about having one supervisor per list (with `one_for_all` strategy) and then a supervisor for these supervisors if needed?

Comment: I thought about that. However the supervisor I want attach children is already sup[ervising some worker nodes. My experiences with Erlang/OTP tell me that I can not mix children types (workers and supervisors).

Comment: @gregorej You can have supervisors and workers at the same level. See http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors